# need an assistance in calculation of the receptive field in keras neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

can you assist in calculation of the receptive field in keras neural network

I've tried to understand how to calculate it but still not sure if u can also explain
i'm alno not sure how to validate it
thanks.

```
def Generator():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=[320,320,3])

    # downsample
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(inputs)
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv1)
    pool1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(pool1)
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv2)
    pool2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(pool2)
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv3)
    pool3 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(pool3)
    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv4)
    drop4 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(pool4)
    conv5 = layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv5)
    drop5 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    # upsample
    up6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(
        layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5))
    merge6 = layers.Concatenate()([drop4, up6])
    conv6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(merge6)
    conv6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv6)

    up7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(
        layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6))
    merge7 = layers.Concatenate()([conv3, up7])
    conv7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(merge7)
    conv7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv7)

    up8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(
        layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7))
    merge8 = layers.Concatenate()([conv2, up8])
    conv8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(merge8)
    conv8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv8)

    up9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(
        layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8))
    merge9 = layers.Concatenate()([conv1, up9])
    conv9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(merge9)
    conv9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv9)
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(3,3, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(5e-4))(conv9)

    model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='U-Net')


    return model
```

i've tried to understand how to calculate it but still not sure if u can also explain
thanks.

Comment: which receptive field are you interested in?

Comment: if i understand your question correct i guess of the final layer or maybe the last conv layer? can a code calculate in in general?